# Podman build files with exit status 100

Tags: python, podman

I'm trying to build a simple podman container but it fails with exit status 100:

Command (not running as root!):
`podman build --tag testscript -f ./script/Dockerfile`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apt update 
RUN apt install -y --no-install-recommends gcc
RUN apt install -y --no-install-recommends python3-dev
RUN apt install -y --no-install-recommends postgresql-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD [ "python", "./script.py" ]
```

Output:

```
STEP 1: FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
STEP 2: WORKDIR /usr/src/app
--> Using cache 91647f078e8ea27aff5b76a287efb3e937fa52f29380701eb9a831b610ad2b1a
--> 91647f078e8
STEP 3: COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
--> Using cache e308b391443ccb8ca4aaeb0155aba78178f016fcab67e61b24759ffac5e4cba6
--> e308b391443
STEP 4: RUN apt update 
--> Using cache 3902ef243d0d124c413f2b76a65dcec2c5d7ef0bcb7a0ab0ef78adab6ed0ed25
--> 3902ef243d0
STEP 5: RUN apt install -y --no-install-recommends gcc
Error: error building at STEP "RUN apt install -y --no-install-recommends gcc": error while running runtime: exit status 100
```

I tried to run the commands one by one in an interactive container (starting from the same base) and they work flawlessly. I just cannot build the image. The host system is Debian 10. Podman is installed exactly following Podman's docs.

```
$ podman -v
podman version 3.0.1
```

Complete debug output: https://gist.github.com/bertmelis/29547341cd4c916fcf470477cfe8d1e9

Comment: Can you add -debug to get more info on the issue ?

Comment: Are you running `podman build` as root or another user?  Also which version of `podman` are you running?  I found this [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1688562) that seems to match what you describe.  The bug says that running `podman build` as a non-root user would not setup the network correctly but it appears it should have been fixed in `podman-1.3.1`.  If you find that you are not hitting this specific bug, check that the network is being setup properly during building.

Comment: not running as root. podman -v gives 3.0.1
Why does building needs a network? It can fetch the needed data. What else is needed? I'm building, not running.

Comment: If the network is not the source of your problem, please post the debug logs for your `podman build` session so there is more information to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bertmelis/29547341cd4c916fcf470477cfe8d1e9

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bertmelis/29547341cd4c916fcf470477cfe8d1e9

Comment: Am not pretty sure, but I can see that gcc is already part of the base image.
Can you try avoid re-install gcc and see ?
https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/cb9a39a6c48d4606a68ae8f986373c9c64d430b5/3.8/buster/slim/Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the base image `FROM python:3.8-slim-buster`, as the name implies you use Python 3.8

However, Debian Buster installs Python 3.7 because the package `python3-dev` is selected. `python3.8-dev` is not available. Without going into detail, this probably causes some conflicts.

The solution is to use base image `FROM python:3.7-slim-buster`